# How can I detect string variable contains mysql_query string in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write function that get mysql_query's variable then fetch and give me an array.
I write these codes:

```
$select_query = mysql_query("...");
fetch_query_objects($select_query);
function fetch_query_objects($query){
$counter = 0;
while ($fetch_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $fields_name = array_keys($fetch_query);
    for ($i=0; $i < count($fields_name); $i++) { 
        $objects[$fields_name[$i]][$counter] = $fetch_query[$fields_name[$i]];
    }
    $counter++;
}
return $objects;
}
```

but in this function I cant recognize `$query` is mysql_query string or not.
how can I detect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer:

```
$select_query = mysql_query("...");
fetch_query_objects($select_query);

function fetch_query_objects($query){
    $objects = array();
    if (gettype($query)=="resource") {
        if ((get_resource_type ($query))=="mysql result") {
            $counter = 0;
            while ($fetch_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $fields_name = array_keys($fetch_query);
                for ($i=0; $i < count($fields_name); $i++) { 
                    $objects[$fields_name[$i]][$counter] = $fetch_query[$fields_name[$i]];
                }
                $counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $objects;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to know how to check of a specific variable is a string, you can use the [`is_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) function.

I would rewrite the function to something like this:

```
$select_query = mysql_query(/* Your query */);
$store_result = fetch_query_objects($select_query);

function fetch_query_objects($query){

    $counter = 0;
    $objects = array();

    while ($fetch_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $fields_name = array_keys($fetch_query);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($fields_name); $i++) { 
            $objects[$fields_name[$i]][$counter] = $fetch_query[$fields_name[$i]];
        }

        $counter++;
    }

        return $objects;
}

/* Use $store_result here */
```

Unfortunately I can't tell if the logic of the function is valid because I'm not familiar with `mysql_*` functions (which are also deprecated). I suggest you start taking a look at [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and start using them ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this..

```
$rows = mysql_nrows($select_query);

   if($row!=0){// execute function 
   }else {
        //don't execute function
    }
```